# Trigonometric inequality with Tangent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

> If $a \in (\pi/2, \pi)$, then $\sqrt{x^2+x}+\frac{\tan^2a}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}$ is always greater than or equal to
>
> (A) $2\tan a$
> (B) $1$
> (C) $-1$
> (D) $-2\tan a$

I know that the $\tan(\cdot)$ function takes its minimum value as $0$. Tried to use this. But I'm not able to eliminate $x$ from my answer.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For positive numbers $a$ and $b$,
$$a+b \ge 2\sqrt{ab}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:   use the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), then consider the sign of $\tan a\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+x} + \dfrac{\tan^2 a}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}}{2} \ge \sqrt{\cancel{\sqrt{x^2+x}} \cdot \dfrac{\tan^2 a}{\cancel{\sqrt{x^2+x}}}} = |\tan a|
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. It was my stupidity that AM GM inequality didn't strike my mind.....